# SKEmiterNode with AVAudioPlayer for music visuals

Tags: ios, swift, animation, avaudioplayer, skemitternode

PLEASE SOMEONE HELP!

I want to have my SKEmiterNode's scale(meaning size) get larger and smaller to the music i have built into the application using AVAudioPlayer. Right now this is pretty much all I have for the SKEmiterNode and it looks great:

```
beatParticle?.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.5)

var beatParticleEffectNode = SKEffectNode()
beatParticleEffectNode.addChild(beatParticle!)
self.addChild(beatParticleEffectNode)
```

All the looks are done in the .sks file.

Here is where I call the "updateBeatParticle" function in a continual loop so that It can where i will put my code for making the particle's scale(meaning size) larger and smaller to the music.

```
var dpLink : CADisplayLink?

dpLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "updateBeatParticle")
dpLink?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

func updateBeatParticle(){
//Put code here
}
```

Any idea how i can do this? I looked at some tutorials such as this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/36475/how-to-make-a-music-visualizer-in-ios

However, i can't quite get my head around it because they're using an emitterLayer and its in Obj-C and am also interested in any other ideas you wonderful people may have!

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: The following code has not been tested. Please let me know if it works.**

Firstly, it looks like you are using SpriteKit, therefore you could put the code needed to alter the emitter scale in the `SKScene` method `update:`, which automatically gets called virtually as often as a `CADisplayLink`.

Essentially all you need to do is update the emitter scale in the `update:` method based on the volume of the channels of your `AVAudioPlayer`. Note that the audio player may have multiple channels running, so you need to average out the average power for each.

Firstly...

```
player.meteringEnabled = true
```

Set this after you initialise your audio player, so that it will monitor the levels of the channels.

Next, add something like this in your update method.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    var scale: CGFloat = 0.5

    if audioPlayer.playing { // Only do this if the audio is actually playing
        audioPlayer.updateMeters() // Tell the audio player to update and fetch the latest readings

        let channels = audioPlayer.numberOfChannels

        var power: Float = 0
        // Loop over each channel and add its average power
        for i in 0..<channels {
            power += audioPlayer.averagePowerForChannel(i)
        }
        power /= Float(channels) // This will give the average power across all the channels in decibels

        // Convert power in decibels to a more appropriate percentage representation
        scale = CGFloat(getIntensityFromPower(power))

    }

    // Set the particle scale to match
    emitterNode.particleScale = scale
}
```

The method `getIntensityFromPower` is used to convert the power in decibels, to a more appropriate percentage representation. This method can be declared like so...

```
// Will return a value between 0.0 ... 1.0, based on the decibels
func getIntensityFromPower(decibels: Float) -> Float {
    // The minimum possible decibel returned from an AVAudioPlayer channel
    let minDecibels: Float = -160
    // The maximum possible decibel returned from an AVAudioPlayer channel
    let maxDecibels: Float = 0

    // Clamp the decibels value
    if decibels < minDecibels {
        return 0
    }
    if decibels >= maxDecibels {
        return 1
    }

    // This value can be adjusted to affect the curve of the intensity
    let root: Float = 2

    let minAmp = powf(10, 0.05 * minDecibels)
    let inverseAmpRange: Float = 1.0 / (1.0 - minAmp)
    let amp: Float = powf(10, 0.05 * decibels)
    let adjAmp = (amp - minAmp) * inverseAmpRange

    return powf(adjAmp, 1.0 / root)
}
```

The algorithm for this conversion was taken from this StackOverflow response https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192481/3222419.